# Find multiple circles with different sizes in image

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv

I need to find circles on an image of different sizes. I cannot show the image itself, but I did try to create a 'dummy-image':

[image]

As you can see: there are several circles, with different sizes. Some are transparent in the middle, some are not. The white circles are important here. The real background is not as even as here since that is a picture, but this might simulate it good.

Now my code should be able to do two things:

1. Find the locations of the centers of the circles.
2. Be able to show how certain it is that these are indeed the locations of centers of the circles.

For the first point:
I tried to use OpenCV templateMatch, which works very good for one size only, not different sizes. I also tried to use several templates with different sizes where the code would loop over, but that takes a lot of time since there should be many templates with different sizes.
Then I tried to use OpenCV Hough Circles, but that one doesn't seem to find every circle:
[image]

Then I tried to use OpenCV findContours, but because the background is not even like the image, too many contours where showed.

Now I have no idea what my other options are.

Is there a nice/good way of finding these circles, including a certainty score per found circle? So how certain is the program that these found points are correct? Is OpenCV the module to use? Or should I use something different (technique/module/method)?

Comment: Blur the image a little to help smooth the background texture. Then threshold the image so you have white circles on black background. Then use findContour. Then get the centroids.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Blur (to smooth the background)
- Threshold
- Apply morphology close and open to smooth
- Get contours
- Draw contours and centroids
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('circles.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply gaussian blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9,9), 0)


# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]


# apply close and open morphology to smooth
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# draw contours and get centroids
circles = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(circles, [cntr], -1, (0,0,255), 2)
    M = cv2.moments(cntr)
    cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    x = round(cx)
    y = round(cy)
    circles[y-2:y+3,x-2:x+3] = (0,255,0)
    print(cx,",",cy)        


cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("circles", circles)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('circles_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('circles_centroids.png',circles)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Result image showing circular contours and centroids:

[image]

Centroids:

```
1395 , 937
492 , 891
1617 , 647
978 , 573
1286 , 295
304 , 227
737 , 140
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also tried this, but this only works when the background is as even as now. Sometimes, when taking the picture, some parts of the background are lighter than other parts. Going to a treshhold image then becomes a mess. Sometimes there are also squares or other shapes in the image, but the only the circles should be found.

Comment: It would be best to see one or more of these images in order to be able to suggest other methods.